# Caffe Installation Issues

Tags: cuda, deep-learning, caffe

I'm having some problem while installing Caffe. Please let me know if anyone have come across the same issue. Thanks.

> make runtest
>   .build_release/test/test_all.testbin 0 --gtest_shuffle
>   Cuda number of devices: 1
>   Setting to use device 0
>   Current device id: 0
>   Note: Randomizing tests' orders with a seed of 88789 .
>   [==========] Running 838 tests from 169 test cases.
>   [----------] Global test environment set-up.
>   [----------] 3 tests from ImageDataLayerTest/3, where TypeParam = caffe::DoubleGPU
>   [ RUN      ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestResize
>   F0107 14:26:04.664185  3079 math_functions.cpp:91] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (11 vs. 0)  invalid argument
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>       @     0x2ab3f5243daa  (unknown)
>       @     0x2ab3f5243ce4  (unknown)
>       @     0x2ab3f52436e6  (unknown)
>       @     0x2ab3f5246687  (unknown)
>       @           0x6bdc35  caffe::caffe_copy<>()
>       @           0x7439af  caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
>       @           0x428da2  caffe::Layer<>::Forward()
>       @           0x62ff53  caffe::ImageDataLayerTest_TestResize_Test<>::TestBody()
>       @           0x657363  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
>       @           0x64de07  testing::Test::Run()
>       @           0x64deae  testing::TestInfo::Run()
>       @           0x64dfb5  testing::TestCase::Run()
>       @           0x6512f8  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
>       @           0x651587  testing::UnitTest::Run()
>       @           0x41d3a0  main
>       @     0x2ab3f8396ec5  (unknown)
>       @           0x4243d7  (unknown)
>       @              (nil)  (unknown)
>   make: *** [runtest] Aborted (core dumped)

#

Ubuntu 14.04

```
/$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92GLM [Quadro FX 3800M] (rev a2)

/$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.29  Thu Jul 31 20:23:19 PDT 2014
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 

/$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
```

#

Comment: *If* DoubleGPU uses double precision (I have no idea if it does), then the error is to be expected. Your GPU does not support double precision floating point.

Comment: May be you don't add CUDA library path (usually /usr/local/cuda/lib64) into LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the GPU support. Maybe it does not support your GPU. I would try installing Caffe without GPU support. All you need to do is to uncomment

```html
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

in Makefile.config and then make again. [Here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) are the instructions.